# How to improve the performance of this Python code?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

Is there any way I can improve the Python code I attached below? It seems too slow for me now.

```
C_abs = abs(C)
_, n = C_abs.shape

G = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n):
        G[i,j] = C_abs[i,j]+C_abs[j,i]
```

Comment: How come this code is working since if d<n, there is an error on the indexation of C_abs in your loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `C_abs` with its [`transposed version`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
G = C_abs + C_abs.T
```

To understand, look at the computation part of the code :

```
G[i,j] = C_abs[i,j]+C_abs[j,i]
```

The first input on the right side is `C_abs[i,j]`, which has the same iterators involved as on the left side of the assignment - `G[i,j]`. So, for a vectorized solution, we will use it without change as the first input. The second input on the right side is `C_abs[j,i]` and its iterators are flipped version of the iterators on the left side - `G[i,j]`. This flipping in the entire array context would be the transpose of `C_abs`. Therefore, put together, we will add `C_abs` with its own transposed version to get the desired output in a vectorized manner.

Comment: Cool! That's amazing!